# How do I show that $F^{∗}(dx∧dy∧dz) = ρ^{2} \sin φ dρ∧dφ∧dθ$.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

I dont know how to solve. Please help me. I need to understand such types of the question for my exam studyings.

Comment: What definition of $F^*$ are you using?

Comment: I know the proposition related to the question is $f^*(w∧n)=f^*w∧f^*n$ but I cannot apply this to my question @ronno

Comment: Please can you show me how to apply?:( thank you @ronno

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that. Do you know any definition of $F^*$ that you're allowed to use? Not just properties. If the problem is from a book, consider adding a reference to the question.

Comment: I know the definition, but not enough. Yes, I found a textbook by myself by studying., T.U. Loring's manifold book. Please let's show me the solution one time. I Will be happy if I Will understand. Because I am studying exam. But I am stuckwith the question. Please help @ronno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta,y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta,z=\rho\cos\phi$, you can get
\begin{eqnarray*}
dx&=&\sin\phi\cos\theta d\rho+\rho \cos\phi\cos\theta d\phi-\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta d\theta, \\
dy&=&\sin\phi\sin\theta d\rho+\rho \cos\phi\sin\theta d\phi+\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta d\theta, \\
dz&=&\cos\phi d\rho-\rho\sin\phi d\phi.
\end{eqnarray*}
Using $d\rho\land\rho=0, d\phi\land d\phi=0, d\theta\land d\theta=0, d\rho\land d\phi=-d\phi\land d\rho, d\rho\land d\theta=-d\theta\land d\rho, d\theta\land d\phi=-d\phi\land d\theta$, it is not hard to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
F^*(dx\land dy\land dz)&=&(\sin\phi\cos\theta d\rho+\rho \cos\phi\cos\theta d\phi-\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta d\theta)\\
&&\land(\sin\phi\sin\theta d\rho+\rho \cos\phi\sin\theta d\phi+\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta d\theta)\land(\cos\phi d\rho-\rho\sin\phi d\phi)\\
&=&\rho^2\sin\phi d\rho\land d\phi\land d\theta.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Ok thank you for help. I have just one question. Well, after your hint,  I can find $dx∧dy∧dz$ by myself. But what Will I do with $f^*$? I dont know this :(

Comment: And in here  "math processsing error" is writing two times. What is this?

Comment: What he's written *is* $F^*dx$, $F^*dy$, and $F^*dz$. His computation is, however, wrong. You should figure out soon enough that you're getting the determinant of the Jacobian matrix when you do this!!

Comment: Ok well, I see everthing right Now. Thank you:))

Comment: What do you mean? I dont understand you. If there exists a mistake, please can you correct this? I am a student. I dont want to learn false:( @TedShifrin

Comment: Generally, $F^*(dx\land dy\land dz)=\frac{\partial^3 F}{\partial(\rho,\phi,\theta)}d\rho\land d\phi\land d\theta$, where $\frac{\partial^3 F}{\partial(\rho,\phi,\theta)}$ is the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: The correct answer should have been $\rho^2 \sin\phi d\rho\wedge d\phi\wedge d\theta$, as you said at the beginning. I presume there's a typo in xpaul's entry above.